# Not condition dates also visible in output

Tags: abap, internal-tables

My requirement is that I should not display the data on a specific date.

Given the select query below it should not display the dates which are present in not condition but in my output I could still see the dates which are present in not condition.

```
REPORT Z_SANJAY_INTERNALTABLES_06.

Tables : EKKO.

Select-options : S_dates for ekko-bedat .

Data : Begin of WA_ekko ,
       WA_EBELN type ekko-ebeln ,
       WA_bedat type ekko-bedat ,
       WA_lifnr type ekko-lifnr ,
       WA_bukrs type ekko-bukrs ,
       end of WA_ekko .

Data : IT_ekko like table of WA_ekko .

select ebeln bedat lifnr bukrs from ekko into table IT_ekko where bedat in S_dates and bedat <> '02.11.2000' .

Loop at IT_ekko into WA_ekko .

write :/ WA_ekko-WA_EBELN ,
         WA_ekko-WA_LIFNR ,
         WA_EKKO-WA_BUKRS ,
         WA_ekko-WA_bedat .
endloop.
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's the problem with the above code? Do you get any error messages when you try to activate the program? Do you get an error when you run it? Or does it just do something different from what you expect it to do?

Comment: Hi @Philipp when I given above select query it should not display the dates which are present in not condition but in my output i could still see the dates which are present in not condition

Comment: I think it's because you formatted the date wrong. It should be in the format `'YYYYMMDD'`. I might write an answer when the question gets reopened.

Comment: Hi @Philipp i have tried with 'YYYYMMDD' Format also but still it is displaying the dates present in not condition. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: you already have the answer in Philipp's comment.